# Is it possible to adjust aspect ratio on an Android device?

Tags: screen, customization, streaming, video-streaming

I have an Android device that has a 4:3 aspect ratio.

When I watch videos in full screen mode, sometimes the aspect ratio causes the video to be distorted.

Is there a way to temporarily adjust the aspect ratio?

I can see a couple different solutions:

1. Adjust the actual aspect ratio.
2. Add a black bar on the top / bottom of the display that effectively changes the aspect ratio.

Comment: Maybe something in the options of the video player used? If not, tried [a different one](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_player) already?

Comment: Try VLC. It supports different display ratios

Answer (score 0):

VLC is the best if they support the aspect ratio you need.

MX Player has a custom aspect ratio setting; and pan, but needs a codec pack to play a couple of audio formats due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the video dimension is equal to your screen, usually the players have a small option in the bottom right/left that looks like a crop symbol. If you click few times on that, the aspect ratio should adjust to your device.

While if the video doesn't match your device screen, there's no way out and you have to crop the video to watch it in full-screen mode. If you are on Android and you know your screen dimension for this cropping task, you can use [Crop & Trim Video editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fnzstudios.com.videocrop) editor that is free and (overall for my standards) watermark-free.